# Is there a differentiation of '=' and '==' in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, operators

I saw some expressions using '==' and some only '=' for comparing values in XPath predicates. At http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp there are only '=' operators mentioned. So are there no '==' operators? If yes, what is the exact differentiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-EqualityExpr) ([and 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-comparisons)) specs don't mention `==` as a comparison operator, only `=`. Perhaps some XPath implementations allow `==` to mean the same as `=` for the sake of confused C/JavaScript programmers.